# Use node.js to specify the extended information about a page in WhatsApp and Discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url

When i post a url into Discord or WhatsApp this pops up. What is it called? I have been searched on how to do this can someone tell me (if possible in express.js or anything that uses node)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag is called Meta Tag

You can specify different meta tags for whatsapp, twitter, etc

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta